# Search Service not working - SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, search, search-results, crawl

When running search service I get the below

**`We did not find any results`**

In central administration – Manage content databases I can see under Database name, search server drop down point at correct server.

In central administration – Services on server

I can see both

```
SharePoint Foundation Search
SharePoint Server Search
```

started.

I can see crawl is enabled.

Central admin – application management – service applications – Manage service applications 
Search Service Application is here
Crawl status = online for crawling
I can see under crawl history regular crawls taking approximately 3:30 mins.

Error messages all seem to be the same
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component. ( Error from SharePoint site: Cannot complete this action. Please try again. )

I have tried following the below

[Search Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/53e54007-48c3-4f3f-9397-b5ee19f92ae8/search-error-hresult-efail-has-been-returned-from-a-call-to-a-com-component?forum=sharepointadminprevious)

But it did not resolved issue

(Crawl is set to run every night at 10pm)

Comment: No w running a full site crawl...any ideas much appreciated!

Comment: Check the even viewer & post the proper error message here.

Answer (score 0):

1. try to recycle the application pool where search is running.
2. If your search servise is running under domain account (as should be), go to Windows services; find SharePoint Server Search 14 Service (OSearch14) and in  properties "Log On" tab provide the correct password and restart the service.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the Windows-Services `SharePoint Search Host Controller` and `SharePoint Server Search 15` solved this problem for me.

I had to perform a full-crawl after service-restart because i cancelled a previously hanging incremental-crawl.